# call a python function from excel

Tags: python, excel, vba

I have a python function that gets exchange rates from a website :-

```
import requests
import time

def myFunction(myCCY,myDate):


 url=f'https://www1.oanda.com/currency/converter/updatebase_currency_0=GBP&quote_currency={myCCY}&end_date={myDate}&view=details&id=5&action=C&'

    headers={
        'accept':'text/javascript, text/html, application/xml, text/xml,*/*',
        'referer':'https://www1.oanda.com/currency/converter/',
        'user-agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/81.0.4044.122 Safari/537.36',
        'x-prototype-version':'1.7',
        'x-requested-with':'XMLHttpRequest'
    }

    resp=requests.get(url=url,headers=headers)
    time.sleep(2.73)
    if resp.status_code==200:
        jsonReturn=resp.json()
        myRate=jsonReturn['data']['bid_ask_data']['bid']
        return myRate
    else:
        return 0
```

I am trying to call it from Excel where I have a list of currencies  :-

```
Sub getRates()
Dim i As Integer
Dim shell As Object
Dim exePath As String
Dim scriptPath As String
Dim command As String
Dim myDate As String

Set shell = VBA.CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")
exePath = """C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/Shared/Python37_64/python.exe"""
scriptPath = "C:/Users/Philip/Documents/python2.myFunction"
myDate = "2020-05-25"
Stop
For i = 1 To Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("rates").Rows.Count
    command = exePath & " " & scriptPath & " " & Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("rates").Range("A1").Offset(i - 1, 0).Value & " " & myDate
    Debug.Print shell.Run(command, vbHide)

Next i



End Sub
```

but it doesnt seem to work.

Is it obvious what I am doing wrong???

Thanks
Phil

Comment: Did you manage to fix your issue ?

Comment: Hi. No I gave up. Can't seem to get it to work